# How do I open an offline website on Android?

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android, browser, firefox-for-android, offline

I have a directory with some `.html` files, some `.jpg`s, an `index.html` file, and some other stuff. If I drag the `index.html` into chrome (or other browsers) on my desktop PC this static/offline website will display in the browser and I can navigate the site without issues.

When I go to the same directory in Android Pie and open the same `index.html` file in Android-Chrome I get the error "file can't be found". I've tried other Android browsers with the same result.

In Android File Explorer the directory (and respective file) appear as:

```
/Internal Storage/my_site/index.html
```

How can I open a simple static offline HTML website on Android? Is there a specific app or browser I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter in Chrome address bar `file:///path/to/file`. In case you aren't sure about the path use any file explorer that tells you the path.

In this case it is `file:///storage/emulated/0/my_site/index.html`

Also many file explorers including MiXplorer offer to open `.html` files with all supported apps (registered mime type):

[image]