# How to view pages saved on storage (or disk)

Tags: browser, offline

I have a very simple html page that I saved on my disk on my computer. It only contains a link to an image, saved in the same folder with that html page.

I can view it without any problems on my computer.
But when I copy the page (and the image) on my phone in a folder, I can't properly view the page. I am using Chrome on the phone.

I know the phone does not have a hard disk, it just has flash memory used as storage, as computers use disks. But "disk" sounds more clear like storage memory (to me).

My page is named "page.htm" and the image it is named "mypic.jpg"
the page only contains this code:

```
<img src=mypic.jpg></img>
```

It works very well on the computer but it doesn't work on the phone.
It looks like the browser simply can't understand links to local files, stored on the phone storage. It doesn't matter the images are in the same folder with the html page. It still doesn't understand where the image is.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Save the page again in a single HTML file with [SingleFile](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile#install) extension, and than open that page in Chrome on Android. It should work.

Comment: Chrome on Windows can save it in a single file without the need of any extension. The file ends in ".mhtml". I can open with Microsoft Edge but Chrome doesn't recognize it. Do I have to instal SingleFile for Chrome to recognize such files?

Comment: What is the reason for Android to put such a heavy restriction? I have books written in HTML. They have hundreds of pages, the pages link to other pages and they link to the images they display. Why Android can't offer such a basic feature? Do I have to install Linux on Android in order to be able to view basic html files with images?

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218492/131553